# how to know the current screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigator

I'm making a chat app and i want to send push notifications to an user only if he is not in the chat screen, so i need to know the current screen or path

I tried saving in state the name of the screen each time he enter to it, but of course it did´nt work when user go back with Navigator.pop or if he uses gestures

I don't know what is the right way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `dispose` method to update the state whenever the user leaves the screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  bool userInChat = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Set the user as "in the chat" when the widget is initialized
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Set the user as "not in the chat" when the widget is disposed (he left the screen)
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The `initState` method is called when the widget is created, and the `dispose` method is called when the widget is removed from the widget tree, `dispose` is typically called when the user navigates away from the screen.